# Create link form external list

Tags: html, list, hyperlink, indexing

I need to create links on a lot of webpages. But those links are going to change quite offen. So I'd like to index them and then call them in my html page. This way if I need to change the url I can do it from a single place i.e a csv file or a text file.
Ideally I'd like to use html or java...

so the steps would be:

- 1. have the url index in a file:

variable 1 = http://www.site.com

variable 2 = http://www.site2.com

- 1. in the html page use the variables instead of the urls.

  < a href="variable 1" >< /a >

Is this possible without using php? (I have no idea how to use php...)

The only work around I found is to create a bunch of html rederection pages and use those smaller urls. But its extremely messy...

Thanks for your help.

Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP just do:

links.php

```
$link1 = "http://www.link.com";
$link2 = "http://www.link2.com";
```

and in your HTML include links.php page in your another php page

```
include_once "links.php";
global $link1;
global $link2;

<b> this is my page <a href="$link1"> click here</a> and <a href="$link2"> and here </a> to find the actual links </b>
```

Comment: Great thanks! After a bit of struggle It worked fine, I didn't know how to use php at all... I used the `<?php echo $link1?>`in the `<a>`.